# MFC- Hide menu item based on command line parameter

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC application where I need to hide one menu item based on the command line parameter which has to be done in CWinApp::InitInstance. Is there a way to hide one particular menu item?

PS: "DeleteMenu" is not an option for me since I cannot re insert the menu item.

Comment: Hide means delete. If you want to show it again, insert the item. If you don't want to delete the item, the only way is to disable it.

Comment: I think both of you should read about `OnInitMenuPopup` and `ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP`